# How to map memory in a device tree

Tags: linux, device-tree

I am trying to create a device tree (dts) manually from scratch. I am using various information from the device in /proc. I need to create the memory node (specifically stuff about the ram). What I know from Googling is that if my kernel code is starting at `40080000` like so

```bash
# /proc/iomem
40000000-4cdfffff : System RAM
  40080000-4154ffff : Kernel code
  41550000-4167ffff : reserved
  41680000-4209cfff : Kernel data
```

peripheral hardware has ram addresses set at prior addresses as follows

```bash
# /proc/iomem
00110b80-00110bff : dvfsrc@10012000
10212000-1021207f : cq_dma@10212000
10228000-10229fff : dramc@1022a000
11000080-110000ff : i2c0@11007000
11200000-1120ffff : usb0@11200000
11220000-11220fff : mt6768-afe-pcm@11220000
11230000-1123ffff : mmc@11230000
11cd0000-11cd0fff : mmc@11230000
4d010000-4d010fff : persistent_ram
4d100000-755dffff : System RAM
  6e000000-6f61ffff : reserved
140000000-23fff5fff : System RAM
```

**Here is my sample DTS**

```
\{
    model = "mediatek,MT6769H";
    compatible = <&model>, "mediatek,MT6768";
    interrupt-parent = <0x1>;
    #address-cells = <2>; // I know This formats reg input
    #size-cells = <2>; // I know This formats reg input
    serial-number = "";
    chasis-type = "handset";

    cpus {
    
    };
    
    // Physical RAM ram
    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x0 0x23fff5fff 0x0>;
        // 0x23fff5fff being the total amount of physical ram /
    };
    
    // Peripheral memory mapping
    reserved-memory {
        mmmc_reserved: mmc@11230000 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "manufacturer,model";
            reg = <0x11230000 0xFFFF>;
        };
    };

    mmc: mmc@11230000 {
        memory-region = <&mmc_reserved>;
    };
};
```

1. List item Should I use the kernel start address as 0x0 or 0x40000000 as the kernel base address?
2. Do I have to record the total amount of physical ram in the memory node?

```
memory {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x0 0x23fff5fff 0x0>;
    // I am thinking the first 0x0 is for the starting point of ram
    // 0x23fff5fff being the total amount of physical ram /
};
```

3. How are the peripheral memory addresses handled when there are two entries

```bash
#/proc/iomem
11230000-1123ffff : mmc@11230000
11cd0000-11cd0fff : mmc@11230000
```

Comment: Have you read `5.3. Memory Reservation Block` in the [Devicetree Specification](https://devicetree-specification.readthedocs.io/en/stable/flattened-format.html)?

Comment: "*I am using various information from the device in /proc.*" -- What is in the **/proc/device-tree/** directory?

Comment: some properties of /proc/device-tree are either blank or phandles so I can't get reference to the actual data which led me to create a kernel module to dump device tree values